# Why when i click Generate button it does update only the first time?

Tags: angular

app.component.html

```
<div>
  <button (click)="onButtonClick()">Generate !</button>
</div>

<div>
  <label>Your Password</label>
  <input [value]="password">
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

  password = '';

  onButtonClick()
  {
    this.password = "My Password";
  }
}
```

When i click the button "Generate" it update the the input value, but when only the first time, i mean when i delete the content of the input and re-click on "Generate" button it does nothing, i was expecting "My Password" to show up every time i click on the button no matter what is the value of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Because you should be using [two-way databinding](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding):

```html
<input name="password" [(ngModel)]="password">
```

Remember that you need to import `BrowserModule` and `FormsModule` in your `AppModule`

```js
@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    ...
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I want to know why ?
i only want to get the content of variable "password" by calling onButtonClick().
it's like <input [value]="password"> can get the value only one time !!!